# How do I enable cache of the Google Analytics file to increase my PageSpeed Insights score?

Tags: google-analytics, page-speed, google-insights

I have the following rule in my .htaccess file:

```
# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

And I have but when I check my page on Google page insights I still see that one `.js` file has not been cached , the file the following file:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

Now how exactly do I cache this file? How do I cache a Google analytics file?